# Php unexpected 'Content'

Tags: php

I am not sure why it's not working in server. It works in local server.

I have this code:

```
$test="<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=euc-jp'>";
```

and I get

> syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING) in /home/public_html/php/contact-me.php on line 2

My server php version is: `7.1.23`

Thank you.

Comment: please show the whole code til there. I guess the mistake is in line 1 (a not closed `'`)

Comment: @jeff this is the full code `<?php
$test="<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=euc-j'>";


?>`

Comment: this is the full code `<?php $test="<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=euc-j'>"; ?>`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Check to see if you don't have some (hidden) unicode in a code editor / hex mode. Edit: This is covered in the possible duplicate posted/flagged by @Jeff

Comment: My guess is you are missing a double quote in a previous piece of code, what that would do is end the string at the double quote it encounters, which will leave you with `Content` as an unquoted string (as far a PHP is concerned).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix There's only 2 lines; look at the error: `syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING) in /home/public_html/php/contact-me.php on line 2` < Plus, the also stated in comments that that was their full code.

Comment: ok @FunkFortyNiner you were right. it was ecoding. Though I saved the file with single qoute `''` the file were saved as `"" double quote`  I then forced to utf-8 encoding and tried again. It worked. Many thanks. you can post it as answer..

Comment: @sadek I used the duplicate flagged by Jeff to close it. Thanks anyways, I'm just glad that this was resolved. And you're welcome, *cheers* :-)

Comment: The curly quotes can have the same effect (because they would leave it partially quoted, or un-closed)  [For Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93f5c4e110fbb456d9747da8828f61f4e76deb14)  That sand box link, with a missing quote, produces the same exact error you had (which was my point).